# ttyUSB0 not found on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, serialization, raspberry-pi

I'm making a code where the pi gets a serial input from a usb-serial board(From the sparkfun RFID starter kit), how can I make this work?

> error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "main", line 22, in 
>     ser = s.Serial('ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=10000)
>    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialutil.py", line 260, in **init**
>
> self.open()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/serial/serialposix.py", line 276, in open
>      raise SerialException("could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
>   serial.serialutil.SerialException: could not open port ttyUSB0: [Errno 2] No such file or >directory: 'ttyUSB0'

The RFID port is the ttyUSB0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing line 22 in main from:

```
 ser = s.Serial('ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=10000)
```

to:

```
 ser = s.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600, timeout=10000)
```

Answer (score 2):

you should check the name of the usb device that it's connected on your raspberry. 
The line below will show you everything that is connected by their ID, plug and unplug your USB device and you will recognise which one will be yours.

```
ls /dev/serial/by-id/
```

After reconizing your device, replace ttyUSB0 with the whole name that appeared for your. 
Mine device is a ARPI600 board and it's name is displayed usb-Silicon_Labs.....

```
serial.Serial("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001-if00-port0", baudrate=115200, timeout=1.0)
```

That is used when you connected a device on the USB ports. When you want to connect via GPIO pins you need another procedure.

Comment: I gave up to find the /dev/ttyUSB0 device, and I tried this one, It worked for me. But I still have no idea why it doesn't come up.

Answer (score 0):

It's the cable. Check the USB cable. All of that yanking